# How to add Icon on GridView Selected Item

Tags: flutter

> Hey  i am new in flutter please help me in my problem.My issue is that when i select a **gridview** item using **inkWell()**  then image and text both no changed. I dont know why **setState**() method not work.

```
 Widget getAdaptor( var index) {
bool isSelected = false;
return InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      isSelected = !isSelected;
      print('' + isSelected.toString());
    });
  },
  child: Container(
      child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(height: 80, width: 80, child: Image.network(imageBaseUrl)),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              '$title',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: isSelected ? Colors.red : Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: isSelected == true
                ? Image.asset(
                    'images/bike.png',
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                  )
                : Image.asset(
                    'images/tick.png',
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                  ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ],
  )),
);  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your widget needs to be a stateful widget, as you are keeping track of isSelected and are updating the UI. With the current setup, the entire widget is rebuilt every time the state is changed, which also resets isSelected to false.

This should do what you want:

```
class Adapter extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _AdapterState();
  }

}

class _AdapterState extends State<Adapter>{

  bool isSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          isSelected = !isSelected;
          print('' + isSelected.toString());
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(height: 80, width: 80, decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red)),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    'test',
                    style: TextStyle(
                    color: isSelected ? Colors.red : Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: isSelected == true
                    ? Image.asset(
                       'images/bike.png',
                       height: 20,
                       width: 20,
                      )
                    : Image.asset(
                        'images/tick.png',
                        width: 20,
                        height: 20,
                      ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just remind me of how I was doing when I was new to this language.

Remember if you want to use `setState(() {});` you need to put **that variable outside a build widget**

So, you can just put `bool isSelected = false;` outside a method and everything will be just fine.

Like this:

```
bool isSelected = false;

  Widget getAdaptor(var index) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          isSelected = !isSelected;
          print('' + isSelected.toString());
        });
      },
      child: Container(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(height: 80, width: 80, child: Image.network(imageBaseUrl)),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  '$title',
                  style:
                      TextStyle(color: isSelected ? Colors.red : Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: isSelected == true
                    ? Image.asset(
                        'images/bike.png',
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                      )
                    : Image.asset(
                        'images/tick.png',
                        width: 20,
                        height: 20,
                      ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
```